# show that if $S$(finite) spans $V$(finite), (but not basis) then $S$ can be reduced to a basis for $V$ by removing appropriate vectors from $S$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$\mathbf{\text{Problem} \ 18:}$ Suppose that $S$ be a nonempty finite set of vectors in a finite dimensional space $V$. Use $\mathbf{problem \ 16}$ to show that if $S$ spans $V$, but is not a basis for $V$, then $S$ can be reduced to a basis for $V$ by removing appropriate vectors from $S$.

$\mathbf{\text{Problem} \ 16:}$
Show that $S = \{x^4, x^4-x^3, x^4-x^3 + x^2, x^4-x^3 + x^2 -x, x^3-1\}$ is a basis for $P_4$. Also, write $P = 1+2x-3x^2+x^3$ as a linear combination of the vectors from this basis.

OK, I already was able to show $16$ by forming a matrix out of each vector and getting a $\text{determinant} = -1$, then row reducing it and solving with $P$ to get a linear combination, but I am having trouble figuring out $18$, and how I'm supposed to "use" $\text{problem} \ 16$ to show what it wants.

It looks like its saying show that if $S$ spans $V$, but is not a basis for $V$ (I'm guessing this only means it's not $LI$), then $S$ can be reduced to a basis for $V$ (I'm guessing somehow make the set $LI$) by removing appropriate vectors from $S$ (I'm also lost on this part, how does one remove appropriate vectors to make a basis? what rules must I follow?)

and how do I apply $\text{problem} \ 16$ to these things I'm supposed to do which looks like it must be in a general proof?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Show that if $S$ is linearly dependent then some vector in $S$ is a linear combination of the other vectors in $S$ (assume you have a dependence relation and pick the first vector with a nonzero coefficient).  Show that removing this vector from $S$ does not change the span.

Without a specific vector space $V$ I'm not sure how problem 16 is supposed to apply directly.  Maybe they just meant for you to be motivated by how you solved 16.

Comment: when you say "(assume you have a dependence relation and pick the first vector with a nonzero coefficient)" how can I pick the "first vector" while showing it in a general sense? do you mean something like: assume v = k1v1 + k2v2 +...+ knvn, with k1 =/= 0, k2...kn = 0, then remove this vector and show it spans? I actually don't even see how this still spans, forgive me if I'm forgetting something obvious right now..

Comment: Lets say your basis is $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$.  Assume you have an expression $k_1v_1 + \cdots + k_nv_n = 0$ such that not all $k_i$ are zero.  Choose any $i$ such that $k_i \neq 0$ (first, last, or whatever.  All that matters is that there's *some* such $i$) and write $v_i = \frac{1}{k_i}(-k_1v_1 - \cdots - k_{i - 1}v_{i - 1} - k_{i + 1}v_{i + 1} - \cdots - k_nv_n)$.  Now you need to show that anything spanned by $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ is also spanned by $\{v_1, \ldots, v_{i - 1}, v_{i + 1}, \ldots, v_n\}$.  Do this by substituting in the above expression for $v_i$.

Comment: which above expression exactly?